# Product Collection With Duplicates (On Purpose) For Admin Grid How?

Tags: magento2, collection, grid

I need to load a product collection that has repeated products in it. I get this error when trying to load a product collection with repeated products:

```
Item (Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor) with the same ID "1" already exists.
Exception in vendor\magento\framework\Data\Collection.php:407
```

I am adding to the product collection source data to approve vendors on a custom extension. Since I'm adding the source items table the same sku will have multiple entries. This is fine. I have referenced these posts already but they don't have the answer that applies to my situation:

[How to allow duplicate entries in admin grid](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/245917/how-to-allow-duplicate-entries-in-admin-grid)

[Magento 2 | Item with the same ID already exists when join tables](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/337381/magento-2-item-with-the-same-id-already-exists-when-join-tables)

My code is like this:

```
        $this->collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(['invsourceitem'=>$inventorySourceItemTable],'e.sku = invsourceitem.sku')
        ->joinLeft(['invsource'=>$inventorySourceTable],'invsourceitem.source_code = invsource.source_code')
    ->where('invsourceitem.vendor_approval = 0 AND invsourceitem.quantity > 0');
```

I also tried aliasing the entity_id like this but then it gives errors that it can't join the EAV tables so that method won't work.

```
$this->collection->getSelect()->columns(['entity_id_alias'=>'e.entity_id'])->columns(['entity_id'=> 'CONCAT(e.entity_id,invsource.source_code)']);
```

I have also tried changing the grid xml file primaryFieldName but that doesn't matter since the error is coming from vendor\magento\framework\Data\Collection.php:407

In addition I suppose I'll need some sort of dynamic autoincrement type primary id field for the collection since it doesn't exist in the table, this is a secondary question once the original problem is solved

Comment: add group by for entity_id column.

Comment: @S.P thanks but I actually need the products to repeat on the grid, it is an approval grid for products by vendor. There can be multiple vendors for the same product.

Comment: you should create custom column to collection, Which has row number , and change entity_id column name to entity_id_original .

Comment: @S.P Yes I tried that it doesn't work :( that was what I called in my answer 'alias' `$this->collection->getSelect()->columns(['entity_id_alias'=>'e.entity_id'])->columns(['entity_id'=> 'CONCAT(e.entity_id,invsource.source_code)']);` it gives an error because when the collection joins the EAV fields it has to have the entity_id field

Comment: Yes, Can you use (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num at collection and set pricmary key for collection this num column.

Comment: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/

Comment: set your provider id field as num column. so it would not repeat.